# Stringr selection of data on location.

Tags: r, stringr

Calling strsplit:

```
example <- (strsplit(data$col, ","))

[[1]]
[1] "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"

[[2]]
[1] "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
```

I thought I could pull the second last value in each; i.e. 4 and 8 via

```
 example <- sapply(example, "[", 1)
```

Is this not the case? I am getting unusual answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two alternatives:

```
sapply(example, function(x) tail(x, 2)[1]) # option 1
sapply(example, function(x) x[length(x)-1]) # option 2
```

Comment: Thank you. I was attempting `tail(2)[1])`. That makes sense. Appreciated.